# Primary key is not increase room android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I'm creating simple database with student and classes.

I created both entities and many to many relation with view models.

But, I notice that id of both is not incremented.

```
@Entity(tableName = "students")
class Student(
    val name: String,
    val lastName: String
) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var id: Int = 0
}
```

this is the result on table creation:

```
        val student = Student("Daniele", "daniele@mail.com")
        val student2 = Student("Daniele", "daniele@mail.com")

        Log.d("test", "student Id : ${student.id}")
        Log.d("test", "student Id : ${student2.id}")
        student Id : 0 student Id : 0
```

Comment: In the second snippet you show how you create an object of type `Student`. Did you add it to database ?

Comment: yes i use studentDao.insert method delcare in studentDao class.
Could be that the id is saved correctly but logging the local object do not increment it?

Comment: I assume that, after the insertion, you are logging the same objects that you created above. You should get them back from database first :)

Comment: val student1 = studentDao.getById(1)
  Log.d("test", "student 1 id : ${student1.value?.id}")

result is null

Comment: If you made sure you inserted more than 1, then make sure it is inserted (log also name and email)
Or simply try to get first student from database (if there are any and log it's data) 
I am quite sure this can't happen if you used autoIncrement

Comment: It's like no data are insert from Dao, because also name or email are null

Comment: Show the implementation of insert method..

Comment: i get the error, i was trying to log data without wating that they are insert, using repository to show on screen data works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code :-

```
    val student = Student("Daniele", "daniele@mail.com")
    val student2 = Student("Daniele", "daniele@mail.com")

    Log.d("test", "student Id : ${student.id}")
    Log.d("test", "student Id : ${student2.id}")
    student Id : 0 student Id : 0
```

Is not getting anything from the database. It is creating the 2 Student objects (so id is 0) and printing them.

You should be inserting the Students into the database and to test them extracting them via the functions defined as part of the respective @Dao class.

e.g assuming a StudentDao interface as :-

```
@Dao
interface StudentDao {

    @Insert
    fun insert(student: Student) :Long

    @Query("SELECT * FROM students")
    fun getAllStudents() :List<Student>
}
```

- Allows a student to be inserted and a List of of Students to be extracted
- **Note** that the Database class  needs to include `entities = {Student.class}` in the @Database and also include `abstract StudentDao studentDao();`

Then after building the Database, in this case into a Database object namd mDB you can use (note the build uses `.allowMainThreadQueries` and also the following is in Java for convenience) :-

```
mDB.studentDao().insert(new Student("Fred","Bloogs"));
mDB.studentDao().insert(new Student("Mary","Smith"));
List<Student> studentList = mDB.studentDao().getAllStudents();
for (Student s: studentList) {
    Log.d("STUDENTINFO", "ID=" + s.getId() + " Name = " + s.getName() + " " + s.getLastName());
}
```

i.e. Adds 2 Students to the database and then extracts the students resulting in :-

```
2019-11-29 00:30:15.568 D/STUDENTINFO: ID=1 Name = Fred Bloogs
2019-11-29 00:30:15.568 D/STUDENTINFO: ID=2 Name = Mary Smith
```

I believe that the equivalent of the above code in Kotlin would be something like :-

```
    mDB.StudentDao().insert(Student("Fred","Bloggs"))
    mDB.StudentDao().insert(Student("Mary","Smith"))
    val studentsList = mdb.StudentDao().getAllStudents()
    for (s :Student in studentsList) {
        Log.d("STUDENTINFO","ID= ${s.id} Name = ${s.name} ${s.lastName}" )
    }
```

Comment: I was using suspend function with coroutine, is that good apporach?

Comment: And now im having really hard problem is add record in many to many table (studentsClassroom) and show them in the same recyclerView

Answer (score -1):

Use below code it will solve your problem.

```
@Entity(tableName = "students")
data class Student(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) 
    var id: Int,
    val name: String,
    val lastName: String
)
```

Comment: I add data to the class definition, nothin change

Comment: Moved the primary key in the consctrutor also is not working. I just pass 0 everywhere i used insert and i still get null

Comment: Go through this link - https://android.jlelse.eu/android-room-using-kotlin-f6cc0a05bf23

Comment: Don't pass any value for primery key

Comment: i try don't pass any value it's complain that i have id as a string (the other name parameter)

Comment: pass like - Student("null,Daniele", "daniele@mail.com") and check.